# Plot fitted probabilities in R with different datasets

Tags: r, ggplot2, polynomials

I want to plot the fitted regression line of a regression in a graph where there is also the binned variables plotted within a range of -1 and 1.

```
lost <- ggplot(data = data_2, 
  aes(x=log_rank_ratio, y=quit, color = as.factor(favorite))) +
  geom_point(size=2) +
  theme_bw() + 
  xlab("Log Rank Ratio") +
  ylab("Observed Likelihood of Quitting Mid-Match") +
  geom_vline(xintercept=0, linetype="dashed", alpha=.7)
```

which gives the following picture (the x-variable in the scatterplot is binned (data_2):

[image]

What I wann add, however, is to plot the fitted lines of the following regression (unbinned x-values in data_1):

```
fit1 <- lm(quit ~ favorite + log_rank_ratio + log_rank_ratio^2 + log_rank_ratio^3 , data = data_1)
```

which should give sth like:
[image]

Comment: Would you be able to share a reproducible dataset?
Without seeing the data you should be able to add your log ratios, favourite category and fitted values into a separate data frame titled `fit_df` or similar, add `geom_line(aes(x=log_rank_ratio, y= fitted, group = favorite), data = fit_df)` .

Answer (score 1):

If you actually want to fit a cubic polynomial then use `geom_smooth` with `method = lm` and `formula = y ~ poly(x, 3)`. You also need to pass `data = data_1` to `geom_smooth`, and if you want the lines to be black, use `color = "black"` *outside* the `aes` and `group = factor(favorite)` *inside* `aes`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = data_2, 
       aes(x = log_rank_ratio, y = quit, color = as.factor(favorite))) +
  geom_point(size = 2) +
  geom_smooth(data = data_1, method = lm, formula = y ~ poly(x, 3), 
              se = FALSE, aes(group = as.factor(favorite)), color = "black") +
  theme_bw() + 
  xlab("Log Rank Ratio") +
  ylab("Observed Likelihood of Quitting Mid-Match") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed", alpha = 0.7)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-08-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

**Data used (inferred approximately from question)**

```r
set.seed(1)

data_2 <- data.frame(log_rank_ratio = c(seq(-2, -0.2, 0.2), seq(0.2, 2, 0.2)),
                     quit = c(189, 177, 191, 212, 209, 213, 225, 249.3, 249.2,
                              249.1, 249.7, 280, 275, 305, 281, 280, 305, 325,
                              326, 275)/1e4,
                     favorite = rep(0:1, each = 10))

data_1 <- data.frame(log_rank_ratio = rep(data_2$log_rank_ratio, each = 10),
                     quit = c(t(replicate(10, rnorm(20, data_2$quit, 0.005)))),
                     favorite = rep(0:1, each = 100))
```